# Centering Camera on Velocity Applied Node Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a subclass of SKNode which consists of a few sprites that make up a player. I would like the "camera" to center on this node (Always have the player in the center). Now before you down vote this for it being a duplicate, hear me out. The Apple documents suggest making the player node completely static, and instead moving around a camera node. However in my case I'm applying multiple properties of physics to my character, including velocity impulses. My first thought would be to just apply these impulses to the camera node itself, however this has become impossible due to the fact that the character has a small soft-body physics engine on it. I'm applying velocity to it like so:

```
player.primaryCircle.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: player.primaryCircle.physicsBody!.velocity.dx+relVel.dx*rate, dy: player.primaryCircle.physicsBody!.velocity.dy+relVel.dy*rate)
```

I managed to get it to partially work with the following code:

```
    override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    self.player.position = player.primaryCircle.position
    self.camera.position = player.position
    centerOnNode(camera)
}


func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {
    let cameraPositionInScene: CGPoint = node.scene!.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node.parent!)
    node.parent!.position = CGPoint(x:node.parent!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, y:node.parent!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y)
}
```

However that didn't 100% work, as seen here: (It should be focused on the red circle)
http://gyazo.com/b78950e6cc15b60f390cd8bfd407ab56

As you can see, the world/map is moving, however it doesn't seem to be moving fast enough to center the player in the middle. (And note that the "Unamed" text is at a fixed spot on the screen -- That's why it seems to always be in the center)

Comment: http://swiftalicio.us/2014/09/2d-camera-in-spritekit/

Comment: is your centerOnNode function called in the update method?

Comment: @Wraithseekerr Yea, it is. I think at this point my only option is to remove all the physics from the player and apply them to the camera, unfortunately this is a decent amount of work but lesson learned I guess. I'll probably be doing using a class similar to what sangony mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should still work with physics unless I am not truly understanding the question. We did something similar with our SKATiledMap with that Auto Follow Feature. What you need to do is make sure the player is added to a node you can move (usually a map) as a child and then in the update function you do something like this...(sorry it isn't in swift)

```
-(void)update
{
    if (self.autoFollowNode)
    {
        self.position = CGPointMake(-self.autoFollowNode.position.x+self.scene.size.width/2, -self.autoFollowNode.position.y+self.scene.size.height/2);

        //keep map from going off screen
        CGPoint position = self.position;

        if (position.x > 0)
            position.x = 0;


        if (position.y > 0)
            position.y = 0;

        if (position.y < -self.mapHeight*self.tileWidth+self.scene.size.height)
            position.y = -self.mapHeight*self.tileWidth+self.scene.size.height;
        if (position.x < -self.mapWidth*self.tileWidth+self.scene.size.width)
            position.x = -self.mapWidth*self.tileWidth+self.scene.size.width;

        self.position = CGPointMake((int)(position.x), (int)(position.y));
    }
}
```

Map being the node that the player is added to. Hopefully that helps. Also here is the link to the git hub project we have been working on. https://github.com/SpriteKitAlliance/SKAToolKit

Comment: This was exactly what I was working for (I just converted it into swift). I'm been banging my head against a wall on this problem forever, thanks so much!